# Moving title block in Pandoc

Tags: layout, pandoc

I have a Pandoc `.md` document which contains a standard, [3-line title block](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example19/Title-block.html) as follows:

```
% title
% author
% date
```

Pandoc converts this document via LaTeX to a PDF:

```
pandoc --variable papersize:"a4paper" -s -S -o output.pdf document.md
```

The title block displays as I expect, but I'd like to **move it so that it occupies a predefined space** -- a centered 100mm x 60mm rectangle starting at 70mm down the page.

I'd be happy to use trial and error rather than exact measurements when trying to place the title block, but at the moment I cant even find a way to move it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did not seem to be possible.

In the end I used a word processor to print out the title page and used Pandoc for the rest.

I'm still open to suggestions, but giving this answer the tick for now.